# CATransform3DScale expecting CATransform3D struct not SCNMatrix4

Tags: scenekit

I am trying to put some 3D text in my app, but I need to scale it, here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
SCNText *text = [SCNText textWithString:@"Some Text" extrusionDepth:4.f];
 SCNNode *textNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:text];
 textNode.position = SCNVector3Make(-1, 5, 0);
 textNode.transform = CATransform3DScale(textNode.transform, .1f, .1f, .1f);
 [root addChildNode:textNode];
```

and I get a

> CATransform3DScale expecting CATransform3D struct not SCNMatrix4
>   or something of the sort.
>   If I don't transform, the text takes up most of the screen.
>   Any ideas?
>   Thanks

Answer (score 2):

on OS X `SCNMatrix4` is a typedef of `CATransform3D` (and thus you can use CoreAnimation utils) but that's not true on iOS. Have a look at `SceenKitTypes.h`, it exposes functions that match the ones of CA such as `SCNMatrix4Scale`.

Also it's strange that the text appears too big in your screen. The default font size is rather small and you must almost always change the geometry's font size for it to fit well in your scene (changing the font size is better than scaling because the discretization of the glyph changes and lead to smoother curves). Is that text the only thing in your scene?

Comment: Thanks.  Yep, I was porting a Mac OSX app, and need to do a different translation.  Works now.  Thanks again.